# Failed to find build tools revision

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android studio version to 2.2.2 i face this error for all build tools versions. even i installed some of theme from android studio again but didn't work.
I tried all other tools versions.

```
Failed to find build tools revision
```

**Update**
it works good with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`
but with `gradle:2.2.3` still got error.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 6):

First, try cleaning and rebuilding your project. You can find `Clean project` in `Build` tab.

If it doesn't work, use SDK Manager to install build tools version you want. Match `build.gradle` file to the version installed. For example, if 26.0.0 version is installed than change your `build.gradle` file to match the following:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) for more information.

Also, check offical [gradle release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions) and check if you have correct versions for all programs. Upgrading Android Studio might help.

Comment: I tried all of these but didnt work! but by changing gradle version to 2.1 it works nice.

Comment: @hessm good you did! Also I suggest upgrading your Android Studio to most recent one.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project right click on project and than select

> open module setting

than in module section select

> your app

and then

> build tools revision

and then select your build version

Comment: Tried and get new error 'Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments'

Comment: In Project level gradle build remove android{} portion

Comment: If you think that my answer for the initial problem helped you, please consider Upvote and accept answer to make is useful to others too. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!